# How to group children by parent in Django-MPTT

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) to create a simple hierarchy in Django-admin. With rest framework I'm exposing an API as following

**models.py**

```
class Bone(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Serializer**

```
class BoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bone
        exclude = ['lft','rght',]
```

**views.py**

```
class BoneViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoneSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['name',]
```

**Which results in:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Clavicle",
        "tree_id": 1,
        "level": 0,
        "parent": null
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Left Clavicle",
        "tree_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "parent": 14
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Right Clavicle",
        "tree_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "parent": 14
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Mandible",
        "tree_id": 2,
        "level": 0,
        "parent": null
    }
]
```

What Do I need to change to group them by parent and tree_id to get a result like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Clavicle",
        "tree_id": 1,
        "level": 0,
        "parent": null,
        "children": [
            {
              "id": 16,
              "name": "Left Clavicle",
              "tree_id": 1,
              "level": 1,
              "parent": 14
            },
            {
              "id": 15,
              "name": "Right Clavicle",
              "tree_id": 1,
              "level": 1,
              "parent": 14
            },
         ],
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Mandible",
        "tree_id": 2,
        "level": 0,
        "parent": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used mptt but after a brief look into the docs something like that should work.

```
class ChildrenBoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bone
        exclude = ['lft', 'rght', ]


class BoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildrenBoneSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bone
        exclude = ['lft','rght',]
```

and in your queryset filter for objects without parents and remember to prefetch.

```
Bone.objects.filter(parent=None).prefetch_related("children").all()
```